# Ruby on Rails - Error but nothing is logged

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, error-log

Hello I'm trying to install the latest redmine (2.5)

And I already setup the environment using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.17
I already setup the passenger and it's already running

But when I'm trying to access it always return the 500 (Internal Error) page
and when I check in the production log, there is nothing printed in it.

Is there anybody here have any idea where I go wrong? or at least how to know what is the error?

Thank you!

Comment: Check if your production log has write permission or not.

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh The permission is 666 (read and write) and when I'm running rake the log is written there, do you have any other idea? Thanks!

Comment: i am not sure if it will work or not but you can try by making the permission 777 and try to check the log by typing tail -f log/production.log

Comment: You could check whether apache logs your errors via `tail -n 100 /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh You're right man, I cannot use the 666 permission because the owner problem, you can create an answer and I will upvote and mark it as correct answer :) Thanks

Comment: @nayoso added the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by making the permission 777 and try to check the log by typing `tail -f log/production.log` 
You have to give full permission for the log file.